# How to speed up country detection from ip adress query?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use geo location ip db from this service:

https://lite.ip2location.com/database/ip-country-region-city

I imported the csv file to my mysql database.Now my table has **2,716,854 rows**. My queries are very slow.

**My table sql:**

```
CREATE TABLE `ip2location_db3`(
    `ip_from` INT(10) UNSIGNED,
    `ip_to` INT(10) UNSIGNED,
    `country_code` CHAR(2),
    `country_name` VARCHAR(64),
    `region_name` VARCHAR(128),
    `city_name` VARCHAR(128),
    INDEX `idx_ip_from` (`ip_from`),
    INDEX `idx_ip_to` (`ip_to`),
    INDEX `idx_ip_from_to` (`ip_from`, `ip_to`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

**My query:**

```
SELECT *
FROM `ip2location_db3`
WHERE ip_from <=1598483915
AND ip_to >=1598483915
```

**Average query time:**

```
1.3627 seconds.
```

**My table looks like this:**

[image]

**How can i speed up this query?**

Comment: Can you run `EXPLAIN SELECT` on your current query?  I would think that your current `idx_ip_from_to` index would be used, and the query would be fast.

Comment: https://imgur.com/V8PAX4M What does this mean?

Comment: It means that MySQL isn't using any index.  May we ask how common is the IP value `1598483915`?  If it be really common, then an index might not speed things up.

Comment: I tried another IP value: 2967684740. Average query time is 0.9 seconds it is still pretty slow

Comment: Honestly for 3 million rows a fraction of a second is not a particularly long time IMHO.

Comment: Is there a way to speed up?

Comment: An index is the way to go.  You need to find out why MySQL isn't using the index.

Comment: I tried with 9 digits ip value and it is using the index. If i try with 10 digits then it is not using the index. Do you know how to resolve this?

Comment: The largest value which can fit into a MySQL integer is `2147483648`.  You may want to check if you defined your table correctly.

Comment: Does `BETWEEN ? AND ?` help? I'm concerned about it being MyISAM which is a very old database engine that has no business being used in 2020. InnoDB is faster when tuned properly, and tuning is usually as easy as allocating more buffer memory.

Comment: Why are you testing for `<= 1598483915` *and* `>= 1598483915`? Why not just for `= 1598483915`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table SQL should follow their FAQ https://www.ip2location.com/faqs/db3-ip-country-region-city#database

```
CREATE DATABASE ip2location;
USE ip2location;
CREATE TABLE `ip2location_db3`(
    `ip_from` INT(10) UNSIGNED,
    `ip_to` INT(10) UNSIGNED,
    `country_code` CHAR(2),
    `country_name` VARCHAR(64),
    `region_name` VARCHAR(128),
    `city_name` VARCHAR(128),
    PRIMARY KEY (`ip_to`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

Then your query should be:

```
SELECT `ip_from`, `ip_to`, `country_code`, `country_name`, `region_name`, `city_name`
FROM `ip2location_db3`
WHERE INET_ATON([IP ADDRESS]) <= ip_to LIMIT 1
```

If you use the above, your query speed should improve by quite a lot.

Comment: MyISAM in 2020? Should be InnoDB. The InnoDB cache can speed up queries considerably. This also requires an `ORDER BY` or MySQL is free to pick a record at random.

Answer (score 0):

Replace SELECT * with SELECT and list fields you actually need.
Currently you are returning fields that are not required like ip_from & ip_to

Comment: Doing `SELECT *` is not efficient, but it won't make performance substantially faster. This table is pretty lean, it just needs better indexing.